# Reading with fscanf segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am currently trying to initialize a 2d array with values but keep encountering a segmentation fault...I noticed it always occurred when I added the fscanf line of code...but I don't understand what's wrong with it since from my understanding it should work...this is a code snippet:

```
    FILE * fp;
        int count, i,j;
        int **arr;

        arr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*9);
        for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*9);
        }    

fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < 9; j++){
                fscanf(fp, "%d", &arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: is `fp` valid here? did you check?

Comment: I'm not receiving any warnings in the terminal?

Comment: added the code snippet for fp...sorry must've missed it when I copied

Comment: Check for `if(fp != NULL)`

Comment: updated the code...sorry it's still not running

Comment: woah...why is it null...I do have a file named input.txt

Comment: What do you mean `why is it null`? fopen can fail

Comment: I'm not too well-versed in C but based on what I know it fails if the file does not exist? I do have a file in the same directory named input.txt though

Comment: ok my mistake...it was failing because the name of the file is "input" not "input.txt". I should not have included the file extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you neither

- checked for the sucess of `malloc()`
- checked for the success of `fopen()`.

For any of the cases,

1. if `malloc()` fails, it will return NULL and using that pointer will cause  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
2. if `fopen()` fails, it will return NULL, and using the file pointer later will again cause [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Put a chcek for sucess of all the library functions (in general) and use the return value only if they are successful.

Comment: apparently fp is showing up as null...though I do have a file on the same directory named input.txt

Comment: In the case of the 2d array I tried initializing the value of the 2d array I made and it did print out the values so it is not null...Also I just figured out that the name of the file was the problem...It should be "input" not "input.txt"...I did not need to add a file extension...my mistake sorry